# org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult:

Tags: thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I am new to spring `mvc` form validation.

I am getting the below error:

```
Field error in object 'RandomModel' on field 'fname': rejected value \Mukul; codes [Max.RandomModel.fname,Max.fname,Max.java.lang.String,Max; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes \RandomModel.fname,fname; arguments ; default message fname,20; default message cant be greater than 20

Field error in object 'RandomModel' on field 'pwd': rejected value ; codes \Max.RandomModel.pwd,Max.pwd,Max.java.lang.String,Max; arguments \org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes RandomModel.pwd,pwd; arguments ; default message pwd,20; default message password cant be greater than 20 characters

Field error in object 'RandomModel' on field 'pwd': rejected value ; codes \Min.RandomModel.pwd,Min.pwd,Min.java.lang.String,Min; arguments \org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes RandomModel.pwd,pwd; arguments ; default message pwd,8; default message min value should be 8

Field error in object 'RandomModel' on field 'lname': rejected value ; codes [Max.RandomModel.lname,Max.lname,Max.java.lang.String,Max; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [RandomModel.lname,lname; arguments ; default message lname,50; default message \maximum length is 50

Field error in object 'RandomModel' on field 'fname': rejected value Mukul; codes \Min.RandomModel.fname,Min.fname,Min.java.lang.String,Min; arguments \org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes \RandomModel.fname,fname; arguments ; default message fname,3; default message min value should be 3\
```

~code~ following is my controller class

```
   @RequestMapping("/randomprocess")
    public ModelAndView randomprocess(@ModelAttribute("RandomModel") @Valid RandomModel    RandomModel,
            BindingResult bindingResult) {
        // System.out.println(model);

        // System.out.printf("%d + %d + %d =%d", 5, 6, 7, 5 + 6 + 7);

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return new ModelAndView("random.html");
        }`your text`

        return new ModelAndView("userAddedConformation.html");

    }
```

```
The model class
```

```
public class RandomModel {

    @Min(value = 3, message = "min value should be 3")
    @Max(value = 20, message = "cant be greater than 20")
    String fname;

    @Max(value = 50, message = "maximum length is 50")
    String lname;

    @Email(message = "enter correct email id")
    String email;

    @NotEmpty(message = "cannot be blank")
    String dob;

    @Min(value = 8, message = "min value should be 8")
    @Max(value = 20, message = "password cant be greater than 20 characters")
    String pwd;

    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }

    public void setFname(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }

    public String getLname() {
        return lname;
    }

    public void setLname(String lname) {
        this.lname = lname;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(String dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public String getPwd() {
        return pwd;
    }

    public void setPwd(String pwd) {
        this.pwd = pwd;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "RandomModel [fname=" + fname + ", lname=" + lname + ", email=" + email + ",  dob=" + dob + ", pwd=" + pwd
                + "]";
    }

    }
```

```
HTML code
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th=http://www.thymeleaf.org>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Hello</title>

<style type="text/css">
.section1 {
    width: 500px;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0px
}

.section1 input {
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0px
}

.error {
    color: red;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <form th:action="@{/randomprocess}" th:object="${RandomModel}">
        <div align="left" class="section1">
            <label for="fname">FirstName: </label> <input type="text"
                th:field="*{fname}" id="fname">

            <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('fname')}" th:errorclass="error"
                th:errors="*{fname}" />
        <br> <br>
        
        
         <label> LastName: <input type="text"
                id="lname" th:field="*{lname}">
            </label>
            
            
            <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('lname')}" th:errorclass="error"
                th:errors="*{lname}"/>
                <br> <br> 
                
                
                <label> Email: <input type="email"
                    id="email" th:field="*{email}">
                </label>
                
            <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('email')}" th:errorclass="error"
                th:errors="*{email}"/>

                <br> <br> <label> DOB: <input type="date"
                    th:field="*{dob}" id="dob">
                </label>
            <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('dob')}" th:errorclass="error"
                th:errors="*{dob}"/>

                <br> <br> <label> Password: <input type="password"
                    id="pwd" th:field="*{pwd}">
                </label>
            <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('pwd')}" th:errorclass="error"
                th:errors="*{pwd}"/>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```